# JMeter 5 - Failed to replace text

Tags: replace, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to use JMeter 5.0 [replace feature](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html)

> Search feature has been improved to allow you to iterate in the tree over search results and do necessary replacements through Next/Previous/Replace/Replace/Find buttons

I can search and find occurrences and find text, but I can't replace it using Replace/Replace All/Replace & Find

Replace All report as `Replaced 0 occurrences`

Replace or Replace & Find returns error:

```
2018-09-26 10:23:49,276 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
```

Example trying to replace text:

[image]

How should I use the replace feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug opened under:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62767

Replacement is not available in JSR223 Test Elements but search should not fail.

Note that Search/Replace feature is not a full search/replace feature as it is intended for correlation:

- so replacement is limited to certain elements (Header Manager, HTTP Request, AjpSampler, AccessLogSampler)
- replacement only concerns the values and not the parameter/header names

Comment: In what elements Replacement is available?

Comment: I couldn't replace also in HTTP Header Manager with name of parameter

Comment: there is surely room for improvement (features and doc), feel free to discuss it on mailing list

Comment: Issue should have been fixed, can you test nightly build tomorrow ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I'll test next week

Comment: Still similar issues in r1842362 as: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
` and  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.SearchTreeDialog.doReplace(SearchTreeDialog.java:263) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:r1842362]
 at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.SearchTreeDialog.actionPerformed(SearchTreeDialog.java:249) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:r1842362]
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]`

Comment: Hello, I added a comment as I am unable to reproduce with nightly build. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:**
Just take a backup before doing this for safety purpose.

Close the jmx file in JMeter.
Open the jmx file in Notepad++ (it will be like xml)
Search and replace whichever you want to and Save
Open the jmx with JMeter, you can find the replaced text